# Mechanism for synthesis of neopentyl iodide using triphenylphosphite/methyl iodide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I was wondering how the reaction between neopentyl alcohol and triphenylphosphite/methyl iodide looks like [from a mechanistic point of view](http://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV6P0830).

It should involve the formation of a phosphonium iodide salt, which can then use the phosphorus' oxophilicity; however, for that to work, the alcohol needs to act as a nucleophile, which in my opinion is not feasable, as alcohols in general are weak nucleophiles.

Comment: The ability of alcohols to act as nucleophiles on phosphonium ions is central to reactions like the Appel reaction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appel_reaction) and the Mitsunobu reaction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsunobu_reaction).

Answer (score 5):

As evident by the Ref.1, the first step is the reaction of triphenylphosphite and methyl iodide to give methyltriphenoxyphosphonium iodide (See path B of Ref.1). This reaction is conditional and some details of conditions are described in Ref.2. Then, one of the phenolate ion in methyltriphenoxyphosphonium iodide is replaced by *neo*-pentyloxy group giving away a phenol molecule. The resulting compound, suggested by the original authors of the method (Ref.2), undergoes $\mathrm{S_N}2$ mechanism to give the resulting *neo*-pentyl iodide in good yield:

[image: Suggested SN2 mechanism]

However, the suggested $\mathrm{S_N}2$ mechanism leans heavily on the claim that rearrangement does not occur, but in light of the finding of Ref.3 (the presence of more than 6% of *t*-amyl iodide in the reaction mixture that can only achieved by the rearrangement of *neo*-pentyl group, loses much of its credibility. Accordingly, to explain the rearrangement, Ref.3 suggests following two paths for the mechanism:

[image: Two paths to neopentyl iodide]

According to Ref.2, $\bf{A}$ and $\bf{B}$ are in equilibrium. The covalent form $\bf{A}$ would undergo “*cis* elimination” thus giving rise to a cyclic transition state, $\bf{a}$ leading to give pure *neo*-pentyl iodide (See Path 1). Alternatively, the ionic form $\bf{B}$ would break up to give an ion pair $\bf{b}$, which collapses to *neo*-pentyl iodide before rearrangement occurs (Path 2). However, when combination of neo-pentyl and iodide ions is delayed, the rearrangement would occur and *t*-amyl iodide would be formed (Also, according to Ref.3, the material balance has never exceeded 80% and the deficiency may well be due to olefin formation).

*References*:

1. H. N. Rydon (Checked by W. Fuhrer, R. Keese, and A. Eschenmoser), "Alkyl iodides: neopentyl iodide and iodocyclohexane (Propane, 1-iodo-2,2-dimethyl- and Cyclohexane, iodo-)," *Organic Syntheses* **1971**, *51*, p.44 (DOI: 10.15227/orgsyn.051.0044); *Coll. Vol. 6* (**1988**), p.830 (4 pages).
2. S. R. Landauer  and  H. N. Rydon, "458. The organic chemistry of phosphorus. Part I. Some new methods for the preparation of alkyl halides," *J. Ckem. Soc.* **1953**, 2224-2234 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1039/JR9530002224).
3. Nathan Kornblum and Don C. Iffland, "Neopentyl Iodide," *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1955**, *77(24)*, 6653–6654 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01629a083).